# XSL Setting Value for checkbox

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSL to populate checkboxes but the `value` is empty. I need the value to be the corresponding `dept`, `region`, and `category`. Please help.

Here is the xsl:

```
<xsl:key name="dept" match="/items/item/dept/text()" use="." />
<xsl:key name="region" match="/items/item/region/text()" use="." />
<xsl:key name="category" match="/items/item/category/text()" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <div class="w3-container w3-cell" style="background-color:#949494">
        <form>
            <xsl:for-each select="/items/item/dept/text()[generate-id()
                = generate-id(key('dept',.)[1])]">
                <input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="{dept}" />Department <xsl:value-of select="."/><br></br>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <br></br>
            <xsl:for-each select="/items/item/region/text()[generate-id()
                = generate-id(key('region',.)[1])]">
                <input type="checkbox" name="region" value="{region}" /> Region <xsl:value-of select="."/><br></br>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <br></br>
            <xsl:for-each select="/items/item/category/text()[generate-id()
                = generate-id(key('category',.)[1])]">
                <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="{category}" /> <xsl:value-of select="."/><br></br>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <br></br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Text.." />
            <br></br><br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <br></br><br></br>
        </form>
</xsl:template>
```

The output should be:

```
<input> type="checkbox" name="dept" value="dept1">Department 1
<input> type="checkbox" name="dept" value="dept1">Department 2
<input> type="checkbox" name="dept" value="region1">Region 1
<input> type="checkbox" name="dept" value="region2">Region 2
<input> type="checkbox" name="dept" value="category1">Category 1
<input> type="checkbox" name="dept" value="category2">Category 2
```

My xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <number>1</number>
        <dept>1</dept>
        <region>region1</region>
        <category>category1</category>
        <description>
            <pp>
                <line>
                    This is line 1 of description of item 1.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 2 of description of item 1.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 3 of description of item 1.
                </line>
            </pp>
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number>2</number>
        <dept>2</dept>
        <region>region1</region>
        <category>category2</category>
        <description>
            <pp>
                <line>
                    This is line 1 of description of item 2.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 2 of description of item 2.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 3 of description of item 2.
                </line>
            </pp>
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number>3</number>
        <dept>2</dept>
        <region>region2</region>
        <category>category2</category>
        <description>
            <pp>
                <line>
                    This is line 1 of description of item 3.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 2 of description of item 3.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 3 of description of item 3.
                </line>
            </pp>
        </description>
    </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line (and similar ones for region and category)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="{dept}" />
```

You are already positioned on a `dept` element at this point, so this code is looking for a child element named `dept`.

To get the value of the current `dept`, rather than a child, do this...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dept" value="{.}" />
```